# Python error: The view form.formapp.views.contact didn't return an HttpResponse object. solve

Tags: python, django

I'm newbie in python and I'm working with a form by using views,urls...
my project name is *projec1* and my application name  is *usersapp*

This is my **usersapp/views.py **

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from users.form import ContactForm

def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if contact_form.is_valid():
            success = True
            username = contact_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = contact_form.cleaned_data['password']
    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm()
        return render_to_response('contact.html', {'contact_form': contact_form})
```

this is my **usersapp/contact.html**

```
{%block title%}
Contact
{%endblock%}
{%block content%}
<h2>Contact</h2>
    <form action ='.' method = 'POST'>
        {{contact_form.as_p}}
        <input type ="Submit" name = "submit" value = "send">  
    </form>
{%endblock%}
```

this is my **usersapp/form.py**

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()
```

this is my **projec1/urls.py**

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
 from users.views import login
 from users.views import contact

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   ('^contact/$', contact),
                     )
```

im facing this error

```
  TypeError at /
  Error when calling the metaclass bases
  module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
  Django Version:   1.4.3
  Exception Type:   TypeError
  Exception Value:  
  Error when calling the metaclass bases
  module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

my error is:

```
  NameError at /contact
  name 'forms' is not defined
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact
  Django Version:   1.4.3
  Exception Type:   NameError
  Exception Value:  
  name 'forms' is not defined
  Exception Location: C:\Users\Documents\MyProjects\projec1\users\form.py    
  in<module>,line 2
  Python Executable:    C:\Python27\python.exe
```

plz guide someone , thank you in advance

Comment: You should include the complete stacktrace. It's not obvious where the exception occurs without it.

Answer (score 1):

The form class definition was wrong, which likely caused that error:

```
from django import forms

# Inherit from `forms.Form`, not from `forms`:
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()
```

There is also a couple of problems in the view function:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        # Not `contact_form is valid()`:
        if contact_form.is_valid():
            success = True

            # `cleaned_data` is all lowercase:
            username = contact_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = contact_form.cleaned_data['password']
    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm()

    # You always want to return a response. Putting the return statement
    # here will fix the error mentioned in the question's title. The 
    # second argument makes `contact_form` available from the template:
    return render_to_response('contact.html', {
        'contact_form': contact_form
    })
```

Comment: im getting the error again, i made modifications  and ran server again to see my expected output. error is :invalid syntax (form.py, line 2) and its showing me the exception area  " users\views.py in <module>, line 4 "

Comment: SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (form.py, line 2)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value: 
invalid syntax (form.py, line 2)
Exception Location: C:\Users\Documents\MyProjects\projec1\users\views.py in <module>, line 4

Comment: It's a syntax error – something is written incorrectly on line #2 in form.py

Comment: from django.forms import *
class ContactForm(forms:Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()
this is my form.py.. im trying to rectify but its not going well

Comment: If I can view it properly you have added a colon in the line class ContactForm(forms:Form) it should not be a colon rather it should be a dot ContactForm(forms.Form). Please update your Question with the correct forms.py and the Error you get.

Comment: k im posting my upadated code again in another page .. plz do reply in that page ...

Comment: Please pass the context to your template as jkbr has mentioned in his view. return render_to_response('contact.html', {
        'contact_form': contact_form
    })

Comment: yes i edited that context in my original file and ran server, this error is appearing after editing that context itself....what extra changes can i do it to run properly...